# How to find a value in a JSON and unset it?

Tags: php, json

So basically I have this page that takes values, json_encodes them and puts them in an array, in a file. Everything works fine, but the only thing I am having problems with is removing some values once they pass a certain date.

So basically, the code is a form, where someone enters their name, email, location, date and a small message. Next, the code takes the existing file, turns it into an array, and appends the new entry into the array, rewrites the file with the new array and closes it. The entries are turned into their own small array, so the main array in the file has arrays within it. The code checks $item[2], which is the date, and if the current date is after that time, then it needs to delete it. I'm just having trouble getting it to remove the JSON so it can delete the entry.

I know this is a lot, and my code is very messy, but I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do.

Here is the code that compares the date:

```
foreach ($arr as $help)
                      {
                        foreach ($help as $item)
                          {
                            if ($item[2] > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
                            {
                            //stuff happens here, ive just cut it out for simplicity.
}
                          else {
                            $delete = [$item[0],$item[1],$item[2],$item[3],$item[4]];
                            $delete2 = json_encode($delete);

                            $open = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
                            $inside = fread($open, filesize('data.txt'));
                            $newinside = json_decode($inside);
                            $newar = [$newinside];

                            $bean = array_search($delete, $newar);
                            echo $bean;


                          }
                          }

                      }
```

That code is definitely wrong, but it's what I've tried already.

Here is the json file after being totally encoded:

```
[["Simon Long","simon@greatnessgroup.com","2018-01-01T01:01","test","aaa"],["test","test@gmail.com","2020-01-01T01:01","yeah","test\r\n"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that we have an `$arr` similar to the output in the question.

Here, we loop through our arrays, then check one by one for a pattern than we wish to exclude, for example the `dates`, using a simple expression:

```
/([0-9]{4}.+)/m
```

Then, we unset the `dates`, just as an example, and `json_encode` our array back to json.

```
$arr = '[["Simon Long", "simon@greatnessgroup.com", "2018-01-01T01:01", "test", "aaa"], ["test", "test@gmail.com", "2020-01-01T01:01", "yeah", "test\r\n"]]';
$arr = json_decode($arr, true);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        $re = '/([0-9]{4}.+)/m';
        preg_match_all($re, $value2, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
        foreach ($matches as $key3 => $value3) {
            unset($arr[$key][$key2]);
        }

    }
}

print json_encode($arr);
```

#### Output

```
[{"0":"Simon Long","1":"simon@greatnessgroup.com","3":"test","4":"aaa"},{"0":"test","1":"test@gmail.com","3":"yeah","4":"test\r\n"}]
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/a76KIM/1/)

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I'm getting at, and I think that is the framework for my solution, but I want it to detect a date, and then delete the whole array that the expired date is in. So it would delete the surrounding name, email, msg etc.